# How to add attribute to all particular children of a node

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

I have the following node in which I want to add attribute to all `add` nodes.

```
<test>
  <add>x1</add>
  <c><add>x2</add></c>
  <b att1="x">x</b>
</test>
```

I tried

```
functx:add-attributes($test, xs:QName('att1'), 1)
```

It can add the attribute to the `test` node. But

When I tried

```
functx:add-attributes($test/add, xs:QName('att1'), 1)
```

It added the attribute to the first add node but returns only add node with added attribute. Then when I tried with `$test//add` it throws error.

When I  tried

```
for $add in $test//add 
   return functx:add-attributes($add, xs:QName('att1'), 1)
```

It returns two add nodes individually. Now, how to restructure the original node to add the attributes to only the specified nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let me point out that there is a difference in how this is done for just in-memory use versus updating the content of the database. For the latter, you could do:

```
for $add in $test//add
return
  xdmp:node-insert-child(
    $add, 
    attribute atta1 { 1 }
  )
```

To change it in memory, which is what functx does, you'll be making a copy of the original, making changes in the copy as you build it. This is called recursive descent and is a pretty common pattern. I wrote a blog post a while ago that shows [how to implement recursive descent](https://developer.marklogic.com/blog/xquery-recursive-descent), but essentially you'll do a typeswitch that, when it encounters an "add" element, creates the new attribute. You can use the functx function for that. Something along these lines (untested):

```
declare function local:change($node) 
{ 
  typeswitch($node) 
    case element(add) return 
      functx:add-attributes($node, xs:QName('att1'), 1)
    case element() return 
      element { fn:node-name($node) } { 
        $node/@*, 
        $node/node() ! local:change(.)
      } 
    default return $node 
};
```

This code assumes that an add element won't have add elements inside of it; if you will, then you'd want to do something like the second case for the first.

Comment: I don't want to change the value in DB. I want to get the value and I want to restructure it with some custom attributes and present it to the transformation. I tried the second approach, but the line $node/node() ! local:change(.)  throws error. I am not sure about the usage of operator "!". This is the error "Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected Junk_, expecting Comma_ or Rbrace_". I tried changing it in many ways but it doesn't work. Please reply. I will also try to make it work.

Comment: What version of MarkLogic are you using? The "!" operator is relatively new. You can replace that line with `for $n in $node/node() return local:change($n)`

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. In office we are using ML7. I tried this sample in my home where I just had ML5. In ML7 it is working.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can replace/insert/delete an element or attribute in two ways.
In-memory change or changing the actual content of the database. 
Since you do not want to change the value in DB, you can use in-memory document updation.

`import module namespace mem = "http://xqdev.com/in-mem-update"     at  "/MarkLogic/appservices/utils/in-mem-update.xqy";`

Instead of using `xdmp:node-insert-child()` you can use 
 `mem:node-insert-child(<x/>, <y/>)`