# How to check for dynamic element names in a typeswitch expression?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

This question is related to [How to add attribute to all particular children of a node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759131/how-to-add-attribute-to-all-particular-children-of-a-node).

```
import module namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com" at "MarkLogic/functx/functx-1.0-doc-2007-01.xqy";
declare function local:change($node) 
{ 
  typeswitch($node) 
    case element(add) return 
      functx:add-attributes($node, xs:QName('att1'), 1)
    case element() return 
      element { fn:node-name($node) } { 
        $node/@*, 
        $node/node() ! local:change(.)
      } 
    default return $node 
};
let $test := <test>
                <add>x1</add>
                <c><add>x2</add></c>
                <b>x</b>
             </test>

return local:change($test)
```

The element in which the attribute to be added needs to be checked dynamically. It is driven from outside. So I tried to send the name of the element to be added as an argument to the `local:change` function but the `typeswitch` `case` is not accepting the dynamic value. How to check this is `typeswitch` expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typeswitch only allows fixed element names, not variables as per definition of XQuery. Instead of matching the `<add/>` elements in the typeswitch, match all elements and use `local-name(...)` (or `name(...)` if you have to match namespaces) instead to distinguish the value.

```
import module namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com" at "MarkLogic/functx/functx-1.0-doc-2007-01.xqy";
declare function local:change($node, $name) 
{ 
  typeswitch($node) 
    case element() return 
      if (local-name($node) eq $name)
      then
        functx:add-attributes($node, xs:QName('att1'), 1)
      else element { fn:node-name($node) } { 
          $node/@*, 
          $node/node() ! local:change(., $name)
        } 
    default return $node 
};
let $test := <test>
                <add>x1</add>
                <c><add>x2</add></c>
                <b>x</b>
             </test>

return local:change($test, "add")
```

Comment: Thanks.. Instead of typeswitch I tried later with only "if then else". That also worked. Thank you.

Comment: You should probably use fn:node-name() rather than fn:local-name(). As written, the code will fail if the element has a namespace. Call with `local:change($test, xs:QName("add"))`, and change the test to `if (fn:node-name($node) eq $name) then`

Comment: It will not fail -- but not test for namespaces, that's why I proposed using `fn:name()` in case you want to verify namespaces. Passing a QName and using `fn:node-name()` might be more elegant, though.

Comment: Note that typeswitch can always be replaced by an if-then-else construct, typically using `if ($x instance of element(x))` conditions - unless your processor does strict static typing, which few processors now do. The main rationale for typeswitch is that it gives better static type information within the conditional branches; hence its restriction to conditions that are statically defined.